# code does not work and not show on project

Tags: django-models

i wanted to write my first project in django. Unfortunatelly my code does not work, the problem is new password and old password doesnot appear in project.

for,s.py:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTuxw.jpg)
class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
new_password1 = forms.CharField(label='New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'current-password','class':'form-control'}))

```
new_password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'current-password','class':'form-control'}))
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

```
urls.py:
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64><token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='app/password_reset_confirm.html', form_class=MySetPasswordForm) , name='password_reset_confirm'),




password-rest-confitm.html:

{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}`your text`
{% block title %}Login{% endblo``hhh``ck title%}
{% block main-content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
            <h3>Password Confirm</h3>
            <hr>

            <form action="" method="post" novalidate class="shadow p-5">
                {% csrf_token %}
                   {% for fm in form %}
                       {{fm.label_tag}} {{fm}} <small class="text-danger">{{fm.errors|striptags}}</small> <br>
                   {% endfor %}
                
                
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" value="Submit">
                <br>
                
                {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                        <p class="alert alert-danger my-3">{{error}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </form>`kkk`
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
{% endblock main-content %}
```